# Getting a strange error here

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have one main flash file (swf) which loads in all it's sub pages from external swf's. When I run my external swf everything works fine, but as soon as I publish it, and try to load it into my main SWF I get this error:
All other pages loads fine (cause they don't look for the .xml file I use in this page).

Any ideas?

```
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: file:///T|/2011/Tjelta%20Eiendom%5FNOV/3%5FProduction/Flash/assets/figures/figures.xml
at figures_fla::MainTimeline/init()
at figures_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
at flash.display::Sprite()
at flash.display::MovieClip()
at buildings_fla::MainTimeline()
```

EDIT: Thanks for the answer. I found a solution while waiting that worked:

```
var myPath:String = loaderInfo.url;
var dataPathTemp:String = myPath.substring(0, myPath.lastIndexOf("/"));
var dataPath:String = dataPathTemp.substring(0, dataPathTemp.lastIndexOf("/")) +
                                                   "/assets/figures/figures.xml"; 
var imgPath:String = dataPathTemp.substring(0, dataPathTemp.lastIndexOf("/")) + "/assets/figures/";
```

Comment: Are you using an absolute path to reference the XML file? Trying using a relative path since Flash's security sandbox will prevent loading external files from an absolute address. Also note the path must be relative to the **main SWF** file doing the loading and not the external sub page.

Comment: After a lot of reading I figured it out while you where replying.. Thanks mate!
Didn't know it hat to be relative to the main swf, since it was the external swf that was loading the file.

Comment: It might also be worth adding that if you embed that main SWF into a HTML page that's in a different location to the SWF then all paths must now be relevant to that HTML page and not the SWF file.

Comment: Thanks =)
For now this is supposed to be run locally on machines.. But I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DJohnson got the answer.
Using absolute paths, extracted at runtime, solved it.